# Json, GeoJSON, agrupar resultado de consulta postgresql

Tags: php, json, postgresql, geojson, openlayers

Estoy experimentando con los Clusters a partir de un fichero GeoJSON generado a partir de una consulta postgresql. Hago la consulta y escribo el fichero. Según como lo hago, cada una de los observaciones que están en la bbdd, en el Cluster genera un punto, pero hay observaciones que comparten id, pq tienen más de una imagen, por ejemplo. Mi duda es como generar el GeoJSON para que salgan agrupadas las observaciones en función del id, y una observación que tenga 2 imagenes, por ejemplo, no salga como dos puntos, si no como uno solo.
La query y el fichero lo genero de este modo:

```
$query = "Select id_observation, a_code, name, long_4326, lat_4326, obs_date, id_observation_font, 
id_image_observation, main_co, author, image, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom, 7) AS geojson FROM observations WHERE id_observation_font != 3 ORDER BY id_observation";

$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
$geojson = array(
    'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
    'features' => array()
);
$i = 0;
while ($line = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'id' => $i++,
        'properties' => $data[]=$line,
        'geometry' => json_decode($line['geojson'], true),
    );
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}
$localiza = json_encode($geojson, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$conta = "../data/observations.json";
```

El JSON (GeoJSON) que obtengo sale de este modo:

```
{
    "type":"Feature",
    "id":22,
    "properties":{
        "id_observation":"51",
        "a_code":"151",
        "name":"one Name",
        "long_4326":"-x.xxx",
        "lat_4326":"xx.xxx",
        "obs_date":"2015-03-17",
        "id_observation_font":"1",
        "id_image_observation":"30",
        "main_co":"f",
        "author":"John",
        "image":"data/IMG1.JPG",
        "geojson":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-x.x,xx.xx]}"},
        "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[-x.x,xx.xx]}
    },
    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "id":23,
        "properties":{
            "id_observation":"51",
            "a_code":"151",
            "name":"one Name",
            "long_4326":"-x.xxx",
            "lat_4326":"xx.xxx",
            "obs_date":"2015-03-17",
            "id_observation_font":"1",
            "id_image_observation":"29",
            "main_co":"f",
            "author":"John",
            "image":"data/IMG2.JPG",
            "geojson":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-x.x,xx.xx]}"},
            "geometry":{
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[-x.x,xx.xx]}
    },
    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "id":24,
        "properties":{
            "id_observation":"52",
            "a_code":"715",
            "name":"other name",
            "long_4326":"-x.xxx",
            "lat_4326":"xx.xxx",
            "obs_date":"2015-06-01",
            "id_observation_font":"1",
            "id_image_observation":"31",
            "main_co":"t",
            "author":"Phill",
            "image":"data/IMG32.JPG",
            "geojson":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-x.x,xx.xx]}"},
            "geometry":{
                "type":"Point","coordinates":[-x.x,xx.xx]}
    }
```

Como veis, la observación 51 tiene varias imágenes, pero no lo obtengo agrupado. En realidad no se si se puede hacer, por eso lo pregunto.

Saludos

Comment: O sea, quieres agrupar las features por observación?

Comment: Si, quiero agruparlas por observación (id_observacion) de este modo si tiene varías imágenes no genere dos puntos, si no unicamente uno